# Docker commands not running through bash script on windows

Tags: windows, bash, docker, dockerfile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a bash script file which is intended til build a docker image.

```
docker build -t imagename .
```

And I get the following error:

> Error : docker command not found.

This is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

echo "Building image"
docker build -t imagename .
```

I run it with the command `bash bashscript.sh`

Comment: do you have docker installed in the machine?  what happens if you type `docker --version` from the command line?

Comment: Yes docker is installed . It I run the docker command in terminal it works properly. But the same command can’t be run through bash file

Comment: can you show us the bash script ? and how you are calling it ?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to help you out. Please read our [ask] page and edit your question.  Including the output of the command above

Comment: I have shared the script in the question.

Comment: @invad0r I have shared the script and way of calling it .

Comment: Are you able to run docker commands directly from bash terminal? If yes, then are you using `sudo` to run docker commands?

Comment: @KapilKhandelwal yes docker runs directly from bash terminal. Also I had used sudo Command to run . Still I get the same error .

Comment: Strange - this should work ?! On which system are you running this ? could you add a `echo $PATH` and `type docker` before `docker build ..`   ?

Comment: @invad0r  path gets printed its too long to be displayed here and the next error, type: docker: not found . What exactly i should be looking into PATH variable ?

Comment: can you run `type docker` directly into console. the path where docker is installed should show up in `$PATH`. e.g. `type docker` => `/usr/local/bin/docker`, now the path `/usr/local/bin` should be in `$PATH` of script.

Comment: @invad0r I got error “The system cannot find the file specified”

Comment: Can any one help me in this ?

Comment: Can you answer my previous question: On which operating-system are you running this ?

Comment: @invad0r windows 10

Comment: where do you run the bash-script ? PowerShell ?

Comment: @invad0r command line of windows

Comment: ok I can reproduce your problem when running `bash script.sh` in WSL which leads to `docker: command not found`. You need to configure docker, install docker in WSL and run WSL-docker againt windows-docker.exe. see: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly